# How to pass php variable inside json_decode function

Tags: php, json

See the below code : I am trying to pass a variable called $search_term inside the json_decode function but it is not working. What do I need to do?

```
$search_term = $this->input->post('search');
//echo $search_term; die();
$jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.bloomapi.com/api/search?limit=10&offset=0&key1=practice_address.zip&op1=eq&value1='.$search_term),true);      
print_r($jsonArray);
```

Comment: You are appending that value to a URL query string. What does `json_decode` have to do with it?

Comment: Try echoing the output of file_get_contents() and see if the json is valid

Comment: You are not trying to pass variable to `json_decode`, you are passing it to `file_get_contents`. Construct that url first and check it agian.

Comment: What does `file_get_contents` return? I guess `false` or invalid json

Comment: @SajithNair check it. http://www.bloomapi.com/api/search?limit=10&offset=0&key1=practice_address.zip&op1=eq&value1=98101

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas try `urlencode` your `$search_term` first; also codeigniter could return `false` if no such value posted.

Comment: Json looks fine. It seems you have some other error elsewhere.

Comment: @baldrs When I am passing static value, in the same place, it is working. For example, http://www.bloomapi.com/api/search?limit=10&offset=0&key1=practice_address.zip&op1=eq&value1=98101

Comment: Try echoing the output of `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Also It is worth wrapped $search_term in urlencode() to make sure characters are encoded properly for use in a url.

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas 

 echo $search_term; and check it's value I think you will get nothing

Comment: @SKG, look at the codes I submitted carefully, I did try with echo $search_term, which is now commented inside my code.

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas are you sure that `$search_term` is not empty, that `REQUEST_METOD` is really `POST` and `search` form variable is really there and not `empty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check it it's correct I just change the post method to get so that I can test it quickly. As it's working fine with get then It work with post value also.

```
$search_term = $this->input->get('search');
$jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.bloomapi.com/api/search?limit=10&offset=0&key1=practice_address.zip&op1=eq&value1=' . $search_term), true);
                                print_r($jsonArray);
```

You recheck your $search_term = $this->input->post('search'); other wise follow my bellow instruction for proper debuging

```
$search_term = $this->input->post('search');
$api_url = 'http://www.bloomapi.com/api/search?limit=10&offset=0&key1=practice_address.zip&op1=eq&value1=' . $search_term;
echo $api_url;exit;
$jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true);
print_r($jsonArray);
```